# add onclick and onmouseover to a canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been trying to do this for a long time, but I can't figure out what to do!

I don't know JQuery, so that won't work for me, unfortunately.

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
  var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

  c.width = '500';
  c.height = '400';
  c.style.border = '1px solid #000000';
  c.style.background = '#b2b2b2';

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = '#ff0000';
  ctx.fillRect(50,50,30,30);
  ctx.addEventListener('click',function(){alert('You clicked me!')},false)
</script>
```

What I want is when a user clicks the square, an alert will pop up, but notinh happens.

Answer (score 2):

The canvas context is used to draw graphics to the canvas. So, instead of trying to add an event listener to your context, you should add it to the canvas (`c`) element like so:

```
c.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // logic...
}
```

If you want the popup to only appear when the click occurs on the red box, you'll need to get the `x` and `y` coordinates of the click, and the check if that falls within your red box:

```js
var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

c.width = 500;
c.height = 400;
c.style.border = '1px solid #000000';
c.style.background = '#b2b2b2';

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = '#ff0000';

var box = {
  x: 50,
  y: 50,
  w: 30,
  h: 30
}

ctx.fillRect(box.x, box.y, box.w, box.h);
c.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  var {x, y} = getCursorPosition(c, ev);
  
  if(box.x <= x && x <= box.x+box.w && box.y <= y && y <= box.y+box.h) {
    alert('You clicked me!');
  }
});

function getCursorPosition(canvas, ev) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
    var x = ev.clientX - rect.left
    var y = ev.clientY - rect.top
    return {x, y};
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: @rac0208 no worries, let me know how it goes or if you have any additional questions

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `ctx` in the graphical context of the canvas, not the canvas itself. The variable which you have named `c` is the one you want to add event listeners to.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I make it so when I click just the square, the alert will come up

Comment: Oh, by the way, if you were trying to add a listener to *just the rectangle* that you drew, that won't work. You can only add event listeners to the canvas element. If you want to... Hah! I was just writing about that when you put your comment up. It'll be up to you to compare the coordinates of the mouse click to the coordinates of the rectangle to know if the rectangle was clicked.